# Locking a drive with FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm having trouble locking my C drive so I can extract some file information later.

```
#define wszDrive L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0"
HANDLE targetVol = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
DWORD stats;
targetVol = CreateFile(wszDrive,
        0,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        /*FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS*/0,
        NULL);

    if (targetVol == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)    // cannot open the drive
    {
        cout << "error in ioControl with volume handler" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }

    if (DeviceIoControl(targetVol,
        FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME,
        NULL, 0, NULL, 0,
        &stats,
        NULL) ==0)
    {
        cout << "Error with targetVol DeviceIo" << endl;
        ErrorExit(TEXT("GetProcessId"));
        system("pause");
    }
```

The Error exit below returns "GetProcessID faile with error 1: Incorrect function."

```
void ErrorExit(LPTSTR lpszFunction)
{
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL);

    // Display the error message and exit the process

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(dw);
}
```

Do you guys have any idea what's going on wrong?

Comment: I think error is because my target volume has the system files installed. Therefore, the function will always fail.

Comment: You are also making some newbie mistakes, like calling `DeviceIoControl()` even if `CreateFile()` fails, and not calling `GetLastError()` soon enough. You need to call it *IMMEDIATELY* after the failing function exits, and DO NOT call anything else that might reset `GetLastError()` before you can call it, otherwise you might get the wrong error code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MSDN docs for [FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) say right off the bat that

> Locks a volume if it is not in use

The C: drive is almost *always* in use.  The only time it's not in use is if you've booted from different media.

Comment: So I want to find a way to use DeviceIoControl with control code FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS to find cluster info of a file but I think the volume needs to be locked for that. Anyway around that?

Comment: MSDN sez that [FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364572(v=vs.85).aspx) gets the cluster info given a file handle, not a volume handle.  There's nothing there about needing the volume to be locked, either.